# Get Client IP in Docker Container using Bridge Mode

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik, docker-network

Running traefik and some services in docker (using docker-compose), I want to find the client IP of where the requests are coming from.

The solutions suggest to use networking mode host, but that is not a solution because it would disable traefik from communicating with other services in the containers.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this?

Comment: Sadly I have not found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [accessLogs](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/observability/access-logs/) for this purpose. Setup the file path for storing access logs while starting you traefik container and look the logs to check the client IP addresses.

Answer (score -2):

Setting the ports configuration of the docker-compose file as follows for the traefik container should work:

```
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        mode: host
      - target: 443
        published: 443
        mode: host
```

This ports capability is only available for docker-compose file format =>3.2.

This avoids setting the whole container in host mode, and allows for the traefik container to still reach other containers in the docker network.

Comment: The question stated bridge mode, but thanks for the answer